# Line breakpoints don't work in some classes

Tags: java, debugging, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm using intellij Idea to debug an application running on tomcat. But I have a problem that in some classes, the line breakpoints don't work(method breakpoints are working fine...but slow). I can get to the specific line of code or inspect variables by stepping in to the class from the method breakpoint or from another class, but the debugger doesn't stop on any line. (IntelliJ shows empty red circle(no cross))

**Update**: This problem is not limited to Tomcat. I have the same issues on Weblogic with different project. So it's either a problem of Idea or Java.

What may be the possible reasons? There are no special compiler options and when I decompiled the class, the LineNumberTables and LocalVariableTables are there. The two classes(the one where line breakpoints are fine and one where aren't) are in the same package. My sources match the deployed code exactly. I've cleared all intellij idea caches(also [system]/jars, which was suggested here: [Debugger doesn't stop at source code in Intellij IDEA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11726778/debugger-doesnt-stop-at-source-code-in-intellij-idea) )

- Java 1.6.0_43 (64bit)
- IntelliJ Idea 12.1.3
- Tomcat 6.0.36
- Debian testing
- It works fine for other developer using Windows so it's not a problem of the project

When I enable debugger tracing in Idea as suggested by the CrazyCoder, I get these results(showing the output when I add/remove line breakpoint in idea):

### Class which is fine

```
==== Enable Breakpoint ====
[JDI: Sending Command(id=25172) JDWP.EventRequest.Set]
[JDI: Sending:                 eventKind(byte): 8]
[JDI: Sending:                 suspendPolicy(byte): 1]
[JDI: Sending:                 modifiers(Modifier[]): ]
[JDI: Sending:                     modifiers[i](Modifier): ]
[JDI: Sending:                     modKind(byte): 5]
[JDI: Sending:                         classPattern(String): com.teamead.fwf.web.controller.ino.datauser.flightplan.EquipmentDefinition]
[JDI: Receiving Command(id=25172) JDWP.EventRequest.Set]
[JDI: Receiving:                requestID(int): 23]
[JDI: Retrieving matching ReferenceTypes, sig=Lcom/teamead/fwf/web/controller/ino/datauser/flightplan/EquipmentDefinition;]
[JDI: Sending Command(id=25174) JDWP.VirtualMachine.ClassesBySignature]
[JDI: Sending:                 signature(String): Lcom/teamead/fwf/web/controller/ino/datauser/flightplan/EquipmentDefinition;]
[JDI: Receiving Command(id=25174) JDWP.VirtualMachine.ClassesBySignature]
[JDI: Receiving:                classes(ClassInfo[]): ]
[JDI: Receiving:                    classes[i](ClassInfo): ]
[JDI: Receiving:                    refTypeTag(byte): 1]
[JDI: Receiving:                    typeID(long): ref=7269]
[JDI: Receiving:                    status(int): 7]
[JDI: Looking up Class, signature='Lcom/teamead/fwf/web/controller/ino/datauser/flightplan/EquipmentDefinition;', id=7269]
[JDI: Sending Command(id=25176) JDWP.EventRequest.Set]
[JDI: Sending:                 eventKind(byte): 2]
[JDI: Sending:                 suspendPolicy(byte): 2]
[JDI: Sending:                 modifiers(Modifier[]): ]
[JDI: Sending:                     modifiers[i](Modifier): ]
[JDI: Sending:                     modKind(byte): 7]
[JDI: Sending:                         loc(Location): com.teamead.fwf.web.controller.ino.datauser.flightplan.EquipmentDefinition:24]
[JDI: Receiving Command(id=25176) JDWP.EventRequest.Set]
[JDI: Receiving:                requestID(int): 24]

==== Disable Breakpoint ====
[JDI: Sending Command(id=25178) JDWP.EventRequest.Clear]
[JDI: Sending:                 eventKind(byte): 2]
[JDI: Sending:                 requestID(int): 24]
[JDI: Receiving Command(id=25178) JDWP.EventRequest.Clear]
[JDI: Sending Command(id=25180) JDWP.EventRequest.Clear]
[JDI: Sending:                 eventKind(byte): 8]
[JDI: Sending:                 requestID(int): 23]
[JDI: Receiving Command(id=25180) JDWP.EventRequest.Clear]
```

### Class which is not fine

```
==== Enable Breakpoint ====
[JDI: Sending Command(id=25182) JDWP.EventRequest.Set]
[JDI: Sending:                 eventKind(byte): 8]
[JDI: Sending:                 suspendPolicy(byte): 1]
[JDI: Sending:                 modifiers(Modifier[]): ]
[JDI: Sending:                     modifiers[i](Modifier): ]
[JDI: Sending:                     modKind(byte): 5]
[JDI: Sending:                         classPattern(String): com.teamead.fwf.web.controller.ino.datauser.flightplan.FlightPlanBackingBean]
[JDI: Receiving Command(id=25182) JDWP.EventRequest.Set]
[JDI: Receiving:                requestID(int): 25]
[JDI: Retrieving matching ReferenceTypes, sig=Lcom/teamead/fwf/web/controller/ino/datauser/flightplan/FlightPlanBackingBean;]
[JDI: Sending Command(id=25184) JDWP.VirtualMachine.ClassesBySignature]
[JDI: Sending:                 signature(String): Lcom/teamead/fwf/web/controller/ino/datauser/flightplan/FlightPlanBackingBean;]
[JDI: Receiving Command(id=25184) JDWP.VirtualMachine.ClassesBySignature]
[JDI: Receiving:                classes(ClassInfo[]): ]
[JDI: Receiving:                    classes[i](ClassInfo): ]
[JDI: Receiving:                    refTypeTag(byte): 1]
[JDI: Receiving:                    typeID(long): ref=7257]
[JDI: Receiving:                    status(int): 7]
[JDI: Looking up Class, signature='Lcom/teamead/fwf/web/controller/ino/datauser/flightplan/FlightPlanBackingBean;', id=7257]

==== Disable Breakpoint ====
[JDI: Sending Command(id=25186) JDWP.EventRequest.Clear]
[JDI: Sending:                 eventKind(byte): 8]
[JDI: Sending:                 requestID(int): 25]
[JDI: Receiving Command(id=25186) JDWP.EventRequest.Clear]
```

Comment: Do you compile with debug info enabled? Can you provide a sample project that will reproduce the problem?

Comment: Yes. Debug info is there(I've decompiled the classes to see that). I think I won't be able to reproduce the problem, because it works in one class and doesn't work on another and I also think the war project wouldn't meet the guidelines about code length posted in the question.

Comment: You can zip and share the sample via Dropbox / Google Drive / whatever.

Comment: crazycoder: I've found out it's not a problem in the project. It works for a colleague :(

Comment: You can run IDEA from the terminal via `idea.sh` and add `-Didea.debugger.trace=ALL` into [vmoptions](http://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/entries/23395793). This may help to understand what happens inside the debugger, messages will be printed in the console.

Comment: crazycoder: When I'm enabling the breakpoint at the class which is NOK, there's one less call. Everything is the same as the OK class up to `[JDI: Looking up Class, ...`. Another call is missing.

Comment: You may have duplicate classes with the same FQN or the class belongs to a module which is outside of the debug scope (not in the dependencies of the code that you debug).

Comment: Another class from the same package can be debugged and I can stop the problematc class at the method breakpoint. Just the line breakpoints don't work and also stepping is a bit problematic. It's really a mystery I'm trying to solve for the third day :(

Comment: How many classes with this name do you have in the project?

Comment: Just one. But the problem is really not in the project, because the debug is fine on other PCs(which are running Windows).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've received further support on intelliJ Idea servicedesk and the issue was temporarily? fixed by removing the war file from my local maven repository.

Answer (score 3):

I had exactly the same problem and have just worked around it - don't know if your setup is the same but my problem was that my class files were being output into a folder under the content root of my module (even though I did have the folder marked as excluded in my module settings).

I deleted all my local class files, updated the Compiler Output settings to point outside my content root, rebuilt the project and now everything is working as expected.

Comment: So you're saying that in your application, the class was packaged twice? I've checked the exploded war and I have only one instance of that class under WEB-INF.
I'm using maven build. What do you mean by "updated the Compiler Output settings to point outside my content root"?

Comment: In my case the issue was with a local class file, not the deployed application. My ant build is packaging the class files under WEB-INF in the war file, but this was also reflected in my local WEB-INF folder in my source tree. When I remove the class files from the local WEB-INF folder, the problem goes away.

Comment: After a build, I don't have any classes in my source tree.